# Finding a limit , dyadic pavings

Tags: calculus

I need to show that the following limit equals $\pi/4$ :
$$\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{2^k-1}\frac{ \left\lfloor\sqrt{4^k-n^2}\right\rfloor\ }
{2^{2k}}$$  I don't know if it is even possible to do so. I was trying to prove that it is possible to pave a unit disk with dyadic squares which intersect each other along their boundaries and whose total area exceed $\pi$-$\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. So I found a paving for the unit disk in the first quadrant. The total area of the paving was this sum where k shows how fine the partition is. The value of this sum when $k$ is $13$ approximates $\pi/4$ up to three decimal places.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the closely related sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1} \frac{\sqrt{4^k -n^2}}{2^{2k}}.\tag{1}$$
We can rewrite (1) as 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{2^k-1} \frac{1}{2^k}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{n}{2^k}\right)^2}.\tag{2}$$
We recognize Sum (2) as an upper Riemann sum for $\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$, with the unit interval divided into $2^k$ equal-sized subintervals.

The given sum differs from Sum (1) in two ways: (i) The term corresponding to $n=0$ is missing and (ii) The floor function changes each term by at most $\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$.

For large (or even medium-sized) $k$, that makes little difference. The missing $n=0$ term changes things by $\frac{1}{2^k}$, and the floor function changes the sum by at most $(2^k-1)\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$.

Thus the Riemann sum (1) differs from the given sum by at most $\frac{1}{2^k}$. Since the Riemann sum has limit $\frac{\pi}{4}$ as $k\to\infty$, so does the sum of the problem.